# Third level menu not showing up on right position with css

Tags: html, css, submenu

After wasting the whole day in efforts i am still not able to set the position of third level Menu. It shows always on top.

This is the Link of fiddle. Please suggest the change.
**Piece of Html**

```
<nav id="menu-main">        
<ul id="menu">
<li class="item-132 deeper parent"><a href="retail.htm">Services</a>
<ul>
<li class="item-132"><a href="retail.htm">Retail Banking</a>
<ul>
<li class="levelThreeAlign"><a href="retail.htm">Sub sub menu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="item-132"><a href="loans.htm">Types of Loans</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="retail.htm">Sub sub menu</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Whole **CSS** and **HTML** in Fiddle.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/messi1987/6e0zmgqd/)

Comment: You need to give it's parent li  `position: relative`. `#menu-main > ul > li > ul > li { position: relative}`

Comment: i don't know why but You guys are 2 Good. Thanks @anpsmn. Your Solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your Problem is fixed*

```
.item-132{   position : relative;}
```

Comment: Your solution worked, too good. i am just changing the third level menu css again and again. but the above comment is excellent as answer too.